# Have sqlalchemy count how many rows are in the table and print it out

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently have a remote mysql table that connects via `create_engine`. after I got the database established with `conn = engine.connect()`, i used `cuteCatNum = conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cat_table;")` to store what should be the output of the command into the variable `cuteCatNum`. But the problem is, that I cannnot show what is the count when I tried `print cuteCatNum`. Also, trying `print str(cuteCatNum)` wouldnt work as it would just print the memory location instead of the output. So my question is, how would I get the number of rows from the remote mysql as simple as possible and have it print it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cat_table;")
```

return an object [ResultProxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy).

You can access the value of this object like this:

```
col1 = cuteCatNum[0]    # access via integer position
col2 = cuteCatNum['COUNT']   # access via name
```

Comment: I tried using both of the code above, but it didn't seem to work. It kept throwing out errors that it doesn't have `__getitem__`. https://gist.github.com/77a8a80bd26c38dc5bab

Comment: Oh I got it! Thanks! I had a for loop that gets the value of cuteCatNum[0] for each row in conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cat_table;").

Answer (score 1):

```
res = conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table;")
```

returns an object ResultProxy, and then use:

```
 rowcount = res.scalar()
```